# TeamCity. Running build after approved pull request in BitBucket

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, teamcity

Can TeamCity run the build changes from Pull Request after Pull Request has been confirmed but not merged?

How configure a VCS Trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exists plugin, for example [pull-request plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11185-pull-request) or develop your plugin based on [WebHooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/managing-webhooks-in-bitbucket-server-938025878.html?_ga=2.138234359.632565459.1554964656-1570047047.1547555287)

Comment: "Senior Pomidor Deleveloper" is a great job. Thx for answer, i managed to figure it out